# ggplot overlay matrix and scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a matrix of continuous values and then plot dots in a subset of squares. Ideally, the dots inside each square would be small enough so that the color of the square could still be seen in the background. Example code:

```
ex <- matrix( c(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5),nrow=3)
p <- ggplot(melt(ex), aes(x=Var1,y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_raster()
x <- c(1,3)
y <- c(2,3)
pts <- cbind(x,y)
p <- p + ...?
```

It doesn't matter if ggplot needs to use something other than geom_raster or the points need to use cbind. I just want to be able to see the colors of the 'ex' matrix in each square and then see black dots in the two specific squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to plot. Perhaps a mock-up plot would help.

That aside, you could do something like this.

```
ex <- matrix( c(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5),nrow=3)

# Wide to long
df <- data.frame(ex) %>%
    rowid_to_column("y") %>%
    gather(x, value, -y) %>%
    mutate(x = sub("X", "", x))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(df, x %in% c(1, 3) & y %in% c(2, 3)), size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I wanted, exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @MarkBower.